# CSS way to adjust a div's height based on another div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains a flexible-area, popup-area and a footer.

- Flexible-area and footer are always present.
- Popup-area is 0, 40px, or 60px, since its contents are
  dynamically changed with js.
- Flexible-area should fill all the space above the footer.

**Is there a css-only method to allow the flexible-area to increase/decrease its height based on the size of the popup?**

With the current css I have, when I delete the popup in the jsfiddle, flexible does not expand to fill the area.

I'm trying to see if I can do this without jquery or flexbox for max compatibility.

Thanks for your suggestions/comments!

https://jsfiddle.net/L8me7fLk/

```css
div {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
#flexible {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 68vh;
  max-height: 80vh;
}
#popup {
  width: 90%;
  max-height: 60px;
  min-height: 40px;
  line-height: 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
#footer {
  width: 90%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #666666;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="flexible">
    1content
    <br/>2content
    <br/>3content
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div id="popup">
    1popup
    <br/>2popup
    <br/>3popup
    <br/>4popup
    <br/>5popup
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With the popup being absolute you don't have any possible way to do this with CSS only. The only solution is JavaScript. Flexbox would also only work when you don't use absolute positioning. What is the problem using JS for this? You don't even have to use jQuery, just plain vanilla JS.

Comment: Adjacent and next-adjacent selectors? jQuery is max compatibility ;)

Comment: Yeah I can use flexbox or js if necessary. Just wondering if there's some cleverness I could try. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The desired result can be achieved with flexbox.

Firstly, it is a good idea to eliminate `<br/>`s from the code. You can place these items in `<div>`s instead.

```
...
<div>1content</div>
<div>2content</div>
<div>3content</div>
...
```

On the container, you can use flexbox to tell it to behave as a column:

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

This will similarly be required for the children, because the layout of contents of `flexible`, `popup`, and `footer` are columns.

Now the most important part. The `flexbile` div should take up the available space, while the div underneath it should not. Therefore, we can apply the following:

```
#flexible {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#popup {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

This tells `flexible` to use available space, and `popup` not to. For more information on how the `flex` selector works, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex

**[JS Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/L8me7fLk/4/)**

Comment: Thanks for the example. Yes, I'll convert this to flex box as you suggested.

Comment: This makes all the child elements display to flex.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=2.5; user-scalable=YES" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; accept-charset=UTF-8">
    <style>
    .EqHeightDiv{
        float:left;
border:solid 1px #ccc;
background:#0CF;
margin:10px;
max-width:300px; 
padding:10px;
}
    </style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function equalHeight(group) { 
        tallest = 0; 
        group.each(function() { 
            thisHeight = $(this).height(); 
            if(thisHeight > tallest) { 
                tallest = thisHeight; 
            } 
        }); 
        group.height(tallest); 
    } 

    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        equalHeight($(".EqHeightDiv")); 
    }); 
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="EqHeightDiv">Here is some stuff</div>
    <div class="EqHeightDiv">Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some stuff Here is some </div>
    <div class="EqHeightDiv">Here is some stuff</div>
    </body>

    </html>
```